# JPQL TREAT AS /LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql

I'm trying the "TREAT AS" function from JPA 2.1 (eclipselink) and I'm stuck with an error from JPA:

Exception Description: ReportQuery result size mismatch.  Expecting [263], but retrieved [197]

Here is my JPQL query (I change some parts to be more explicit):

```
String jpql = "select distinct s, accountAD "
            + "from SheetAccountUser s "
            + "left join fetch s.userTarget target "
            + "left join TREAT(target.accounts AS ADAccount) accountAD ";
```

ADAccount is a subclass from AbstractAccount (@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED).
A User have a list of AbstractAccount.

I want to select sheets with the AD account of the userTarget. I want null if there is no userTarget or if the userTarget has no AD account (left join).

The problem comes from the treat operator. The SQL generated query have a left join between the AbstractAccount table and the ADAccount table.
This cause the retrieve of one line per account type of the targetUser.

Here is the SQL query generated:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
t0.Id, --etc
t6.Id, t6.name, --etc
t7.userId --etc
FROM sheet t0 
LEFT OUTER JOIN user t6 ON (t6.Id = t0.userTargetId),
account t7 LEFT OUTER JOIN ad_account t8 ON ((t8.userId = t7.userId) AND (t8.idApp = t7.idApp))
WHERE (t7.userId = t6.Id) AND (t7.DTYPE = 'ADAccount');
```

We can see the left outer join between account and ad_account. 
Also, the ad_account table is not present in the select clause.
(The idApp field is a part of the primary key and maintain the unique (userId, idApp) constraint).
I don't know if it's a problem with my understanding or JPA.

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Try simplifying the query and then posting the SQL (there is no need for all the joins to just demonstrate your issue).  Treat should be forcing a join between subclass tables and/or filtering on the type field, so I'm not quite clear on what you are expecting.

Comment: Sure, I added the sql query and simplified the jpql.

Comment: Just realized you likely are expecting nulls to be returned with the left join, while your SQL has an inner join between t7 and t6 (target and accounts I assume).

Answer (score 1):

```
 "select distinct s, accountAD "
                + "from SheetAccountUser s "
                + "left join fetch s.userTarget target "
                + "left join target.accounts accountAD where TYPE(accountAD) = ADAccount";
```

This request doesn't return sheet that have a target without AD Account.

```
 "select distinct s, accountAD "
                + "from SheetAccountUser s "
                + "left join fetch s.userTarget target "
                + "left join target.accounts accounts "
                + " join TREAT(accounts AS ADAccount) accountAD";
```

This one generate the same SQL that my first jpql request and generate an Eclipselink error.

I also have multiple lines for one sheet if the target has one AD Account and at least one other Account type: One line with the AD Account attributes setted and others with null values (these different values block the distinct clause, so do the DTYPE value).

Fortunately, I just need 2 informations about AD Account: Its existence and one boolean "desactivated".

After more reflexion I had an idea:

```
    "select u, "
                // 0 if line with no target or no ADAccount or with another account type, else 1 (one 1 by sheet/target) 
                + "sum( "
                + "     case "
                + "     when accountAD.desactivated is not null then 1 "
                + "     else 0 "
                + "     end "
                + ") as ADAccountExists, "
                // the target have an AD Account desactivated
                + "sum( " 
                + "     case "
                + "     when compteAD.desactivated = 1 then 1 " 
                + "     else 0 "
                + "     end" 
                + ") as ADAccountDesactivated " 
                + "from SheetAccountUser s "
                + "left join fetch s.userTarget target "
                + "left join treat(target.accounts as ADAccount) accountAD "
                + "group by s,target " //the group by maintains unicity of the sheets
```

It's working fine but it's very ugly. I hoppe someday to find another method.

Answer (score 0):

The TREAT expression is meant as a way of allowing access a subclass' parameters within the query; filtering is a necessary byproduct but not the main intent.  It is more along the lines where you might want a query for "People who are workers with a salary > 100k or people who are managers with the number of directs <10".  In that case, a strict join between the people+employees and people+managers would hinder the query.

The TYPE expression allows you to control the filtering yourself so that you get the strict results you are looking for.  Something like:

```
"select distinct s, accountAD "
            + "from SheetAccountUser s "
            + "left join fetch s.userTarget target "
            + "left join target.accounts accountAD where TYPE(accountAD) = ADAccount";
```

Might be more what you need.  Remember that you will need to explicitly list any subclasses you want included though.

If you must use Treat to filter but want outer joins over target.accounts, try something like:

```
"select distinct s, accountAD "
                + "from SheetAccountUser s "
                + "left join fetch s.userTarget target "
                + "left join target.accounts accounts "
                + " join TREAT(accounts AS ADAccount) accountAD";
```

might work, though you may want to just use the TREAT within the where clause when needed.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I also need to filter the properties of the ADAccount class but I think I can use the TREAT in the where clause too. I will try.

Comment: I tried and JPA joins all AbstractAccount subclass tables (and there is a lot of tables T.T). I have to make work the TREAT function...

Comment: If you are expecting your first query to work but finding null target.accounts are being filtered, this is expected - the spec states in 4.4.9: "That is, in the case of a join, the referenced object does not participate in the
result, and in the case of a restriction, the associated predicate is false".  In this case, TREAT(target.accounts AS ADAccount) will force an inner join over target.accounts.   This is the reason I believe the spec uses Treat in the where clause for most of its examples.

Comment: Can you give me the link of the specs please?