# jpa/hibernate criteria query with treat and join on downcasted entity

Tags: hibernate, criteria-api, jpa-2.1

I have the following domain model with inheritance:

```
@Entity
class A {

   @OneToMany           
   Set<B> b;

}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE", discriminatorType = @DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 3)
abstract class B {

   @OneToMany           
   Set<C> c;

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("B1")
class B1 extends B {

   @OneToMany           
   Set<C> c;

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("B2")
class B2 extends B {
}


@Entity
class C {

}
```

I want to build a query that load some fields from C as follow:

```
    class Dto {

        String a;
        String b;
        String c;      

        public Dto(String a, String b, String b) {
          ....
        }

    }

    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery query = cb.createQuery(Dto.class); 
    Root<A> from = query.from(A.class);
    Join<A, B> joinB = from.join(A_.b);
    Join<A, B1> joinB1 = cb.treat(joinB, B1.class);
    Join<B1, C> joinC = joinB1.join(B1_.c);
    q.where(cb.equal(joinC.get(C_.id), cid);
    q.select(cb.construct(Dto.class, joinC.get(C_.value), joinB1.get(B1_.value), from.get(A_.value));
    e.createQuery(q).getResultList();
```

It seems, it's not possible to use treat in more joins, the treat must be a leaf join.
see [eclipselink](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/toplink/jpa-extensions-reference/jpql.htm#TLJPA630), or SO [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100905/jpql-treat-as-left-outer-join).
What happens is that hibernate (4.3.6, the version I'm using) doesn't generate the alias in the jpql query.
Have I misunderstood the use of treat operator?
Is there a way to workaround this issue?

Comment: Did you find any get around for this?